# Можно ли заполнить массив с помощью foreach

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach, scanner

Можно ли заполнить массив с клавиатуры с помощью `foreach`? Суть какая: создаю список и хочу заполнить данными с клавиатуры, пока не введу "стоп-слово".

Comment: Так массив надо или список? В принципе не важно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе можно.

```java
String stop = "STOP";

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

String[] array = new String[scanner.nextInt()];

int pos = 0;

for (String s : array) {
    String value = scanner.next();

    if (value.equals(stop))
        break;

    array[pos++] = value;
}
```

Но это глупо, ведь всё равно приходится хранить индекс элемента, а переменная `s` вообще не используется.

Приравнять `s` к `value` нельзя из-за того, что `String` - ссылочный тип, при присваивании переменной типа `String` нового значения, старое значение в памяти остаётся, но переменная начинает ссылаться на новое значение в памяти.

---

`foreach` используется только для чтения массива, но не для записи в него.

В вашем случае стоит использовать цикл `for`.

```java
for (int pos = 0; pos < array.length; pos++) {
    ...
}
```